# MVVMCross PCL REST call works in Android not in Windows Phone

Tags: mobile, windows-phone, httpclient, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

have the following piece of code in a PCL

```
class CallSAPService : ICallSAPService
    {
        public string MakeSAPRestCall(string url, string jsondata, string username, string password)
        {
            string retmessage = "";
            try
            {
                NetworkCredential cr = new NetworkCredential();
                cr.UserName = username;
                cr.Password = password;
                HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                handler.Credentials = cr;
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
                 Uri Auri = new Uri(url);
                StringContent content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(jsondata.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var result = httpClient.PostAsync(Auri, content).Result;
                 Task<string> ff = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                 retmessage = ff.Result;

                 //StringContent content2 = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(jsondata.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                 //var httpClient2 = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
                 //Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient2.PostAsync(url, content2);
                 //response.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                 //var res = response.Result;

                 // retmessage =  res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ToString();
            }    
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                retmessage = Ex.Message;
            }

            return retmessage;
        }
    }
}
```

this works in Andorid but not in Windows Phone project . In windows phone project the line:
  `Task<string> ff = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` does not come out execution

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this line is your problem:

```
retmessage = ff.Result;
```

You can't do synchronous I/O on the UI thread in Windows Phone.  Use async and await instead of Task.Result.